# Android : Duplicate Activity Getting created on Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have specified an activity in my GCMIntent service class that need to be opened whenever user receives broadcast from server. Below is code in my GCMIntent class:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
String payload=msg.substring(msg.indexOf("RequestResponse=")+20, msg.indexOf("from")-2);
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ListActivity.class), 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("xxx").setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Update List")).setContentText("Update List").setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

So on Broadcast message click my ListActivity is supposed to open which will refresh the List based on data received from server. Issue is if my ListActivity is opened in foreground so on broadcast click the ListActivity is created again and then I have practically 2 instance of same activity one over other. Its working fine if some other Activity is in foreground.
I did some research and it seems that we shouldn't use the code to determine the foreground activity in production. Some posts suggest that using Activity Manager to know the current foreground activity is to be used only for debugging purpose.
I know this

Comment: @Luciano : Did you down vote this due to indentation?

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question @Gaurav

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez Ok.I thought it got down voted due to indentation. Apologies for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ListActivity in your manifest file.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

EDIT: Since `onResume()` will always be called when bringing activity back from background, you may update the list with data received directly in `onResume()` and nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this isn't working. I have to refresh list shown by ListActivity for each broadcast received. Using above solution, in a way freezes the activity as such, since it is already opened nothing can be updated.

Comment: Since `onResume()` will always be called when bringing activity back from background, you may update the list with data received directly in `onResume()` and nowhere else.